# CSS selector does not find element with provided class

Tags: html, web-scraping, css-selectors, scrapy

The html I am trying to scrap looks like this:

```
<a class="mobile_board_link" href="board.php"><b>...</b></a>
```

I created following css selector for the elements:

```
.mobile_board_link a::attr(href)
```

But if I execute it in the scrapy shell it will not even find any a elements with the class mobile board link. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `a.mobile_board_link` instead

Comment: It does not even find the a elments. Is [href] an alternative syntax to ::atr()?

Comment: Sorry. See my modified comment

Comment: Where did you find the`::attr(..)` syntax? It is wrong. The normal CSS syntax for an attribute is indeed `[href]`. Or is this a Scrappy extension?

Comment: @Mr Lister: It's part of Scrapy. It returns the value of the given attribute as a string (though you do still need to extract this string after selecting, using .extract()). Interestingly, it appears in a CSSWG draft known as [Non-element Selectors](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-nonelement), though I'm sure it's existed in Scrapy long before.

Comment: @BoltClock Ah, thanks. I'm not too familiar with Scrapy, as you can see by my typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your selector:

```
.mobile_board_link a::attr(href)
```

Problems:

- space means descendant, so you are trying to find anchors inside your `.mobile_board_link` instead of finding an anchor with that class
- (**the text in italic, which follows is mistaken, as pointed out in the comment section and it was reflected in this very post at the bottom**) *as already pointed out in the comment section you need `[href]` instead of `::attr(href)`*

So this is how your selector should look like:

```
a[href].mobile_board_link
```

EDIT:

Apparently `::attr(href)` is correct in Scrapy, therefore this is a correct selector:

```
a.mobile_board_link::attr(href)
```

Comment: If they're looking for the value of the href attribute, there is no need to select the element by its href using [href], they can just use ::attr(href) to obtain the value directly. It's a feature of Scrapy.

Comment: @BoltClock thank you for pointing that out, I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: maybe consider removing the incorrect information from this answer (about ::attr being wrong)?

Comment: @eis you are right I was wrong there, however, for historical reasons I kept it and made sure that it is fixed in the edit. You are right though since people not reading the whole post will remain with the impression it is not correct. I would like to keep it, so the criticism of BoltClock will remain a valid comment, but the post will make sure there are no misunderstanding. I will do it now, bear with me.